# How do I see the diff of a merge commit in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In the git window of IntelliJ IDEA, I can see the diffs of a regular commit. But, if the commit is merge commit, nothing happens when I press cmd+D (show diff). How do I see the diff of a merge commit in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: As far as I know, IntelliJ does not support this, but [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) does.

Answer (score 1):

To compare a merge commit with one of it parent commits, just select both with ctrl-click and diff them with cmd-D as usual. It might be hard to scroll down to the proper parent though.

It could be that cmd-D on the merge commit would actually show the merge conflicts and how they were resolved respective to the parent commits, but I have not tried. If the merge did not have any conflicts, such a view would be empty, of course.

Comment: Ya, that kind of works but only for 1 parent and it only shows the difference of the 1st file when diffed with the other parent. Maybe, I should try some other git gui app.